# AWS S3 bucket folder tagging for user access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am setting up personal folders for all the employees. We have about 300 employees. Each will have its own S3 folder. Is it possible to tag each folder in the S3 bucket to control user access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An S3 folder is basically an object. You can add an IAM policy to control user access to each object (or folder). In your case, adding 300 policies is not feasible. So, you could use "policy variables" that enable you to add a single policy that works for all users (depending on the user name) as explained in the following blog post:
[Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke)

Comment: Does S3 allow me to tag folders?

Comment: @ljaerj No, it does not